# Apache lost actual request URI

Tags: java, apache, tomcat6

I have apche configured on top of tomcat.

When I forward a request using apache mod_rewrite(proxy) and the rewrited request is forwarded to tomcat, how do i fetch the actual request URI before forwarding the request in java code?

For eg:

Actual url:

http://www.abc.com/xyz/pqr.shtml

Url rewrite using apache:

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^(.*).abc.com$    [NC]

RewriteRule     ^/(.*)/(.*).shtml$  /article/index.dot?reqURI=%{REQUEST_URI}        [NC,P,L,QSA]

The above request is fwd to tomcat.

Now how do i get "/xyz/pqr.shtml" in java code which was the actual request uri?

Comment: You are using Mod Rewrite to rewrite the URL to forward to Tomcat, but in Tomcat (sic. your App code) you want the original URL back?  I don't think that is possible...you just re-wrote the URL to be something else.

Comment: Yes i dont even know dat is conceptually possible or not.

Comment: I think the whole point of Mod_Rewrite is to re-write the URL to something else. The only way I could see this working is if you did a forward to Tomcat, as then you could look in the header to see where you were forwarded from.  Other than that, maybe there is a way to write a cookie out that you could then retrieve back on the Tomcat-side.  Without a good understanding of the requirements it's hard to try and recommend an alternative approach.